# Google Firebase server persistent connection invalid_token

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to use the Firebase server SDK to monitor a value at a specific path. I followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) yet after some time passes, I start seeing log errors like:

```
[WARN] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: invalid_token (Access denied.)
```

I'm using the latest release:

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.0
```

I followed the Java guide for [Installation & Setup for Servers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) exactly yet this error still occurs after some time and it doesn't invoke any code I can hook into to attempt to re-authenticate. Has anyone had a similar issue and know of a resolution?

**Update 2016-05-31:**

I enabled debugging and I see that the persistent connection thread is indeed refreshing its authentication after these warnings.

I can also narrow down the scope of this problem based on this information and further testing:

Any long running `ValueEventListener` attached to a `DatabaseReference` before a token refresh stops receiving data after the initial token expires. For example, a listener attached right after application startup.

Attaching a new listener to a database reference and then disposing of the listener after I get results works fine.

However, this behavior defeats the "live data" aspect of Firebase. You cannot expect - as of 3.0.0 anyway - a listener to receive data for the life of the application. It seems like there's a major bug in Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: We've released the 3.0.1 SDK which should resolve this issue.

We've uncovered a bug in the 3.0.0 Firebase Java Server SDK where it can fail to re-authenticate to the Firebase Database backend. This will happen if your process runs longer than an hour and you don't have any active listeners (in particular at the one hour mark). You will see the `[WARN] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: invalid_token (Access denied.)` error appear repeatedly in the console log.

We'll be releasing a new version (firebase-server-sdk 3.0.1) shortly with the fix. Until then, you can likely work around the issue by keeping an active listener (e.g. addValueEventListener() on a dummy location).

Sorry for the inconvenience! We'll try to get the fix out as soon as possible.

Comment: Please note that you may be missing a related issue. The dummy listener you refer to will not receive data after re-authentication. My question specifically mentions this use case.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  As discussed on the Google Group though, I suspect it's still the same underlying issue.  We've released 3.0.1 with the fix.  Can you give it a try and let me know (mikelehen@google.com) if you're still seeing issues?  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, the bug I noted here still exists in 3.0.1.

Comment: Ack! Thanks for following up.  I'm disappointed to hear that didn't resolve the issue. Let me dig in again and get back to you.

Comment: @Scott Unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue you're hitting with the 3.0.1 release. I've tried a couple different usage patterns, but the SDK is successfully fetching new tokens as necessary and never hits the error you mention. Can you email me (mikelehen at google.com) with more details about how you're hitting this (a code snippet that reproduces the issue would be ideal)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the issue Following the steps in [Installation & Setup for Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#server-sdk-setup). In my case this happens when using a newly created Service Account. However if you use an existing service account e.g Compute Engine default service account, the log message is not being displayed.

The only difference between my newly created service account and the existing one is that the new account is not an Editor member in IAM page.
Trying to add the new account as an Editor in IAM page results in an error.

Comment: Thanks but my service user already has the editor role. It seems more like the issue is related my access token being refreshed and the persistent connection thread isn't handling token updates properly.

Comment: @Scott I have updated the answer with the correct scenario.

Comment: Still not the problem, but thanks. As I mentioned, my service user _does_ have the editor role. I also updated the question a bit to reflect my latest findings.